# google admink reports api disabled_reason

Tags: google-admin-sdk

Today (October 24, 2017) the reports api stopped returning the disabled_reason field.  I have a program that uses GAM (google apps manager) to generate a report on all of our user accounts and then parses the disabled_reason field ( https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/usage-ref-appendix-a/users-accounts ) to find the date on which the account was actually suspended.  Since that field appears to have been removed since yesterday, my program broke this morning.  Does anyone know if there is a log of changes to the API or a reason why this field has been removed?

Thanks - Dan

Answer (score 0):

So far the account parameters was [last updated](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/usage-ref-appendix-a/users-accounts) on **August 22, 2017**. Also the issue tracker was [updated](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/support#bugs) last March 30, 2017. I think you can try [this](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/support#top_of_page) first to make sure it is not a bug.

Comment: I did put in a bug report and it was assigned and a comment posted -https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68197197 that it was "This was (temporarily?) removed due to a security/privacy issue".  Unfortunately this broke my program, so I'm hopeful they will work out the privacy issue and restore the disabled date info to that field.